# How can I create a 1 to 1 Swipe Carousel in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-website

I am trying to custom build a 1 to 1 movement jQuery carousel. I would like for it to work just like [SwipeJS](http://swipejs.com)  does where the carousel moves as you slide your finger.

Unfortunately I can't use the wonderful SwipeJS as this project requires some deep customization of the carousel that SwipeJS wont allow.

I was just wondering if someone could point me in the right direction of how to get started with a iOS carousel that moves as your finger moves on the screen (in jQuery).

UPDATE: This was my attempt http://jsfiddle.net/atlchris/cTt6c/ but it is not working as I had hoped.

UPDATE 2: I think I am getting closer: http://jsfiddle.net/atlchris/cTt6c/1/ This works better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have it figured out: http://jsfiddle.net/atlchris/cTt6c/2/

1 to 1 movement via jQuery!